# Eclipse Jar-in-Jar fails to find a joda.time class

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Eclipse has 3 runnable JAR export methods. One of them does not work in my case. I want to stop using the export method that makes a library sub-folder and switch to a single JAR.

In all cases my invocation is in a script, with a few script variables such as $MEMORYOPTIONS

`java $MEMORYOPTIONS -enableassertions -classpath VARIOUS-SHOWN-BELOW topLevelDomain.domain.packageName.className $1 $2 $3`

Firstly...

I have success with the following export method and the class path as shown.

`export > runnable jar > extract required libraries`

`-classpath /home/user/workspace/project/project1.jar`

I have a reason for not wanting to use this single JAR. (It is because unpackaged third party packages expose files with duplicate names so I get annoying warnings. Example: A file called License.txt is in several packages.)

Secondly...

As already mentioned I also have success with the following "library sub-folder" export method and class path as shown.

`export > runnable jar > copy required libraries into a sub-folder`

`-classpath /home/user/workspace/project/project1.jar:/home/user/workspace/project/project1_lib/*`

(Edit: As it turns out the JAR has a manifest that points to the project1_lib subfolder so the class path can be simplified to omit that. Just delete the part after the colon (:) separator from the class path.)

Thirdly...

I interpret "package required libraries" to mean a JAR-in-JAR export. Invoked with the class path shown, this export results in a failure to find the class.

`export > runnable jar > package required libraries`

`-classpath /home/user/workspace/project/project1.jar`

The error is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadablePartial`

How do I get this particular type of Eclipse export to work? I have already uninstalled Eclipse (Mars) and reinstalled. I have also
removed the `org.joda.time` package and added it back. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider creating an **uber jar** ?

With **maven** you just need to add the following plugin definition and use the command **mvn package**

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>

            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>joda-time:joda-time</artifact>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**</include>
                    </includes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll consider using add-ins when all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the bundled `JarRsrcLoader` with your class as an argument:

```
java $MEMORYOPTIONS -enableassertions 
-classpath /home/user/workspace/project/project1.jar 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
topLevelDomain.domain.packageName.className
```

However, this doesn't allow you to pass arguments (`$1 $2 $3`) to the called class.

Answer (score -1):

You should launch your app using `java`'s `-jar` option. Something like this:

```
java $MEMORYOPTIONS -enableassertions -jar /path/to/project1.jar $1 $2 $3
```